# Invalid syntax python

Tags: python, syntax

I've just started Python,
and everything I was doing was working well until I encountered syntax errors when there were apparently no problems :

```
def things():
    answer = int(input()
    if answer == 1:
        print("wowie my friend")
```

and I get invalid syntax on the ":" after the if, I don't know why.
Thanks for helping me

Comment: `answer = int(input()` is missing a closing `)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware of the parenthesis ! Each open one **must** be closed. It's a common mistake, but always make sure to check you didn't forgot or put an extra one if you have an `InvalidSyntaxError`.